# How to backup and restore everything of foobar2000?

Tags: backup, restore, foobar2000

What is the best way to backup and restore all my everything in Foobar2000?

I was once clicked on a "Reset all" button which provide somehow a stupid feature - clear all setting and playlist.

The story tell that, remember to do backup when there is nothing goes wrong. (And I don't think they should put the button on the middle of all the configuration screen.)

But how? Are there any script or plugins to help me to backup all settings?
I cannot find a button of export or import my settings.

Comment: "I was once clicked on a "Reset all" button which provide somehow a stupid feature - clear all setting and playlist." - This is like that time I clicked on a "Cancel" button which provides somehow a stupid feature - it cancelled my changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be complete: if you're in portable mode, all is saved in the program directory.

And for automatic saving you could use the plugin [foo_jesus](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=68528)

Answer (score 3):

Foobar2000 configuration is stored in profile directory. You can backup that directory to save the settings. Check out the Foobar2000 wiki for more details:
[Foobar2000 wiki](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Directories)
[Forum discussion about Foobar2000 settings backup](http://www.abxzone.com/forums/f96/how-do-i-backup-my-foobar2000-103506.html)

Answer (score 0):

I found this article on [www.howtogeek.com](http://www.howtogeek.com/) which suits your need: [Backup and Transfer Foobar2000 to a New Computer](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19035/backup-and-transfer-foobar2000-to-a-new-computer/)